# For loop being ignored in class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class for getting information from table-like files (like csv files, where data is stored in rows and the columns are separated by commas). When i run it, the row methods work, but the column ones don't. While debugging, the for loops are passed over, but when i test the code outside the methods, they work. Any thought on why it's behaving like this?

You have part of the code here (as it is, it should return the number of columns, instead it returns 0):

```
class DataSheet:
    def __init__(self, address):

        self.dataSheetFile = open(address, 'r')
        self.numberOfRows = self.getNumberOfRowsInFile()
        self.numberOfColumns = self.getNumberOfColumnsInFile()

    def getNumberOfRowsInFile(self):

        numberOfRows = 0
        for row in self.dataSheetFile:
            numberOfRows += 1
        return numberOfRows

    def getNumberOfColumnsInFile(self):

        numberOfColumns = 0
        for row in self.dataSheetFile:
            numberOfColumns = row.count(',') + 1
            break
        return numberOfColumns

    def getIndexRow(self, index):

        numberOfRows = 1
        for row in self.dataSheetFile:
            if numberOfRows == index:
                return row
            numberOfRows += 1

    def getIndexColumn(self, index):

        column = ''
        newLine = '\n'
        for row in self.dataSheetFile:
            column += row.split(',')[index-1] + newLine
        return column

dataSheet = DataSheet('address/DataSheet.txt')
print(dataSheet.numberOfColumns) # => 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over the file you opened twice. But doing that is something that *changes* the file handle you opened. It has a secret internal 'position' where it currently is reading the file, and after reading the entire iterator, you've reached the end.

You can reset the position by doing `f.seek(0)` after reading it.

Comment: Thanks! I used it before each return in the methods and now it works perfectly!